# CheckBox setSelected not working when using android:drawableRight property

Tags: android, checkbox

My Checkbox inside xml layout:

```
<CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:button="@null"
                        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:text="Trending Stores"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Inside onCreate() method of the related activity:

```
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
cb1.setSelected(true);
```

This doesn't show a selected state when I run the app instead checkbox appears unselected. Can't figure out how to solve this issue. Also i need to show the checkbox on the right side and so I am using the property android:drawableRight. I have tried with using custom drawable xml file too, but I am still stuck with the same problem. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand you want the check box placed right in your screen?? Can you post a screen shot or  something to indicate what you want?

Comment: cb1.setChecked(true); try this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ah, ordinarily we don't use `setSelected` for a `CheckBox`.

I think you should use `setChecked` unless you know exactly what you want to do with `setSelected`.

Comment: also can do it in xml with `android:checked="true"`

Comment: Yeah was using wrong method..figured it out a bit later..but thanks for the reply.